# Will select parallel query help for non-indexed column in where clause?

Tags: sql, indexing, query-optimization, database-tuning

the table being queried has billions of records and the select query's where clause is based on non-indexed columns. So a normal select query does a full table scan & hence takes more time. 
I am trying to use parallel feature to see if it helps improving time. But wanted to know , if parallel will really help for Select queries on a single table with where clause on non-indexed columns ?

Example :

```
Select /*parallel(customer_data,4)*/ customer_id,name from customer_data where time_create >= :<min_time> AND customer_status='P'
```

Comment: You might want to add what type of RDBMS you are using, and also on how you plan to 'force' the system to use a parallel approach.

Answer (score 0):

In general, adding parallelism to a query that is a full table scan will help. However there are always things to take into account.

1. Your example shows a comment, not a hint - you are missing the + (plus) sign, so parallelism will not be applied. You should have

   `select /*+ parallel( customer_data, 4 ) */ customer_id, name`...
2. How many rows will be retrieved from your table? The answer to this question is not about where you can use parallelism, but more about whether you *should*
3. How many CPU cores does the database server have and how much IO bandwidth does the storage provide? Parallelism (by design) can consume a large amount of resource; and often the amount of IO bandwidth available is not enough to support a high degree of parallelism. A very rough rule of thumb, is that each CPU core can consume between 50 MB/s and 200 MB/s